# Select when 2 columns are totally different

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is what I want to do, for example if I got 13742 as a ReceiverId, I don't want to get the same Id as a senderId, and vice versa, if I got 13747 I don't want it to be a ReceiverId.
Thank you for your help!

```
SELECT mov.Texto, t.Id as receiverId , mov.Id as senderId
FROM #tmp t 
INNER JOIN #tmp mov ON  t.Id <> mov.Id
    AND mov.Planta = t.Planta 
    AND mov.Ingreso = t.Ingreso
GROUP BY mov.Texto, t.Id, mov.Id



Texto                             receiverId senderId
Viaje ---: GR(VAC) SL 14:00(PRO)    13742   13747
Viaje ---: GR(VAC) SL 14:00(PRO)    13743   13747
Viaje ---: LOCAL SL 12:00(PRO)      13742   13743
Viaje ---: LOCAL SL 12:00(PRO)      13743   13742
Viaje ---: LOCAL SL 12:00(PRO)      13747   13742
Viaje ---: LOCAL SL 12:00(PRO)      13747   13743
```

Comment: Given your example data you want _no_ output since every value of `receiverId` appears in the `senderId` column and vice versa? Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: That's right, sorry, I'll check the link

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<`:

```
FROM #tmp t INNER JOIN
     #tmp mov
     ON  t.Id < mov.Id AND
         mov.Planta = t.Planta AND
         mov.Ingreso = t.Ingreso
```